# Pydev tags import as “unresolved import” all compiled extensions

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, python-extensions

PyDev with Python3.5 seems unable to recognize imports from c-compiled extensions, including packages compiled via Cython.

I am working on an up-to-date debian/stretch machine with a stripped-down self-installed (in home dir) Eclipse/Neon with PyDev added via update site, if it matters.

I have both "Python 2.7.13" and "Python 3.5.2+" installed.

One of the problematic packages is lxml. I installed the debian packages and also tried installing manually via pip (and re-created the interpreter in eclipse afterwards to ensure full finding). In all cases packages *do* work.

In Python2 everything works as advertised.

Under Python3 PyDev flags `from lxml import etree` as error (but resulting program works):

```
Unresolved import: etree    richiedi_certificato_dispositivo.py /trasmissione-telematica/Serializzazione    line 8  PyDev Problem
```

**Note:** I *can* `import lxml` with no error, but then any access  to `lxml.etree...` will be flagged in error. Data completion is consistent (i.e.: `etree` won't be in the offered list).

`lxml` is installed in the usual location:

```
mcon@vocore:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml
total 2156
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8152 Sep  5  2014 builder.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3366 May  5  2016 cssselect.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18387 May  5  2016 doctestcompare.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7641 Sep 25  2011 ElementInclude.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9490 Aug 20 06:48 _elementpath.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1710088 Aug 24 10:14 etree.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan  3 08:58 html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan  3 08:58 includes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     551 Oct  7  2012 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Jan  3 08:58 isoschematron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17450 Aug 20 06:48 lxml.etree_api.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8902 Aug 20 06:48 lxml.etree.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  366440 Aug 24 10:14 objectify.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan  3 08:58 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      92 Sep  5  2014 pyclasslookup.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8531 Nov 20  2014 sax.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     230 Sep 25  2011 usedoctest.py
mcon@vocore:~/trasmissione-telematica$
```

As You can see `etree` is in a shared lib, as is `objectify`; a quick check shows also objectify is not handled by PyDev. I checked a few other "c-extension" packages (e.g.: `import pycurl` and `from Crypto.Util import strxor`) with the same result, so it *seems* a problem with "C" extensions.

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution to this? (I have exactly the same problem, but cannot use xml.etree...)

Comment: @TonnyMadsen: unfortunately not. They are still flagged as errors, but everything works (aside from completion, of course). If You are able to find a solution please inform me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put the offending packages in the forced builtins (as described in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html)?

If that doesn't work, do you have some error in your error log? (see http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on getting it)